# Extract max value from Array <String> in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

Is there a way to extract max value from a String array in Hive ?
I need to do it within a select statement, so explode and join aren't an option.

```
ch = ["4", "9", "1"];
SELECT MAX(ch);
```

returns `["4", "9", "1"]`

Comment: looks like max function here is receiving the entire array as a single value, hence returning the same thing. You would need to convert those into a table. I'm not sure how to do that on Hive but it would be something like `select max(c) from function_array_to_table(ch)`

Comment: How about using sort_array and then getting the first/last element?

Comment: @JorgeCampos: I cannot define any UDF. I need to do this with built-in Hive funtions. 
Any idea on what function_array_to_table can be ?

Comment: @NickW Works but very slow!

Comment: One reason why it’s not generally good practice to store arrays in a relational database, especially in a DBMS that’s optimised to process arrays

Comment: Sorry. Not really, as I said I'm not familiar with Hive but this would be the general approach on every other sql database.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was missing a “not”… especially in a DBMS that’s not optimised to process arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code ...

```
SELECT value=MAX(CAST(value AS INT)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('["4", "9", "1"]','"',''),'[',''),']',''), ',')
```

Comment: This returns:  cannot recognize input near 'STRING_SPLIT' '(' 'REPLACE' in joinSource